# Is it possible to keep deleted (recycled) items forever in a specific list or site?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, recycle-bin

I have a list where items are deleted frequently.

These list items are not too relevant and they can be deleted (permanently), but ideally I would want them to stay in the system for historic purposes, and not disappear entirely when retention kicks in.

It is possible to setup (disable) recycle bin retention on a given list, site or site collection? Or maybe there's an alternative solution that would behave similarly?

Changing the setting at the web application level is not something I can do since it would affect other sites.

I'm kind of hopeful, since there are other similar things we can do at the list level, such as disable list threshold, etc., but I am prepared to accept 
'No' as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, there is only option to change recycle bin thresholds on web application. But you can set set Second Stage Recycle bin to: ADD XX percent of live site quota.

[image]

Set on all sites quotas and on the one, where you want to keep documents in bin, leave it empty. Where the site quota will be empty, the second recycle bin will be unlimited.

[image]

Another way is to create second list or library as a Archive and move the items/files here instead of deleting them.

Comment: thanks. looks promising. where exactly is the quota defined for individual site collections?

Comment: in Central Administrations > Application Management > Site Collection >Specify quota templates and Configure Quotas and Locks

Comment: I think that only allows me to setup a template to the usual options, which are, total storage limit. existing site don't have a specified size limit. so, maybe, you are saying that right now, if I delete the item from the "end user recycle bin" and keep it in the "deleted from end user recycle bin", they will be kept indefinitely? thx

Comment: Yes, they will should stay in Second Stage (Administrator) bin forever, but make sure you have lots of storage, cause it will take some in future. Sites which have quotas, they will have second stage bin like 10% so 100MB, and everything will be cleared but if you havent set storage quota, this bin will be unlimited. If you satisfied, mark my answer please :)

Comment: I see. I guess items are left in the "end user" recycle bin and eventually get deleted. will send them to the second stage and see what happens. thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, you can also adjust the First Stage Bin from 30 days.